# :hover { border-bottom } on "Related" list in questions causes list to "jitter"

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, css

Just a quick note to say that (using Chromium 31.0.1650.57) the `a:hover { border-bottom: ...; }` attribute on the items in the Related list shown when viewing any question pushes all links below the `:hover`ed item down by 1 pixel.

Edit: This appears to occur on this Meta site too.

To save 50ms of thinking - this is fixed by adding `a { border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; }` (or similar, like `padding-bottom: 1px`). :P

Comment: I can confirm this in google-chrome 30.0.1599.114. It seems to only happen on [unix.se], at least it doesn't on [su].

Comment: Despite the "status-completed" tag, the problem still exists, as described [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4550/52236).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting, fix is waiting in repo for build. Should be live in couple hours.

Just FYI: I'm working in Stack in Design team

Comment: Wow, hi. Thanks for letting me know, I just got back to the computer and can confirm this is no longer happening. I am *very* curious - did you only notice my report recently? (Hmm, `margin-bottom: -1px`. Fascinating solution.)