# On the Unix SE, "related" tab 1px wiggling on hover

Tags: bug, design

The cause of the problem is the rule

```
.question-hyperlink:hover,.answer-hyperlink:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #666;
    text-decoration: none
}
```

The result is wiggling if the mouse goes over the link.

On other sites I didn't experience this effect.

I think you could set `border-bottom-width` to 0 in the `#h-related` box.

Screenshots:

[image: Not hovered][image: Hovered]

Comment: The "original" has a "status-completed" tag, which is clearly not true in the case of this report (as also the screenshots show).

Comment: I'm who originally reported the issue (3 years ago). On Chrome 58, if I mouseover the Related list on the right of this page, I don't get any jitter on hover. Where are you seeing it?

Comment: @i336_ Now also I can't see the problem. The rule I refered seems still exists, but there is currently also a `-1px` negative margin now.

Comment: Ah, cool. I wonder if you had some kind of pathological CSS caching issue.

Comment: @i336_ I don't think, the URLs of the SE css files contain their build version as GET parameter. (And I exterminated all cache and retried with different browsers before the report.)